# Replace only every nth value in a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to create a program that could replace a specific word in a string.

Sample word:

```
Dim sample As String = "TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE STAR FISH"
```

I want to replace the second word TWINKLE into MAD so the new output would be:

**TWINKLE MAD LITTLE  STAR FISH"**

is this possible?

Note

```
sample.text =  sample.Replace("TWINKLE", "MAD")
```

function will replace both TWINKLE to MAD and O/P will be

```
"MAD MAD  LITTLE  STAR FISH"
```

which I don't want. Only the second `Twinkle` should be changed

Comment: This is not give me code site. Please show us what have you tried. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This method should work, it just uses string methods like [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceNthValue(input As String, oldValue As String, newValue As String, nth As Int32, Optional comparison As StringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture) As String
    Dim index As Int32 = input.IndexOf(oldValue, comparison)
    If index = -1 Then
        Return input
    End If

    Dim counter As Int32 = 0
    While index >= 0
        counter += 1
        If counter = nth Then
            Dim before As String = input.Substring(0, index)
            Dim after = input.Substring(index + oldValue.Length)
            Return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", before, newValue, after)
        End If
        index = input.IndexOf(oldValue, index + oldValue.Length, comparison)
    End While

    Return input
End Function
```

Your sample:

```
Dim sample As String = "TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE STAR FISH"
Console.Write(ReplaceNthValue(sample, "TWINKLE", "MAD", 2))
```

Output:

```
TWINKLE MAD LITTLE STAR FISH
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceNthValue(input As String, oldValue As String, newValue As String, nth As Int32, Optional comparison As StringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture) As String
    Dim parts = input.Split(New String() { oldValue }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim replacements = parts.Skip(1).Select(Function (x, i) if(i = nth - 1, newValue, oldValue))
    Return String.Join("", parts.Take(1).Concat(replacements.Zip(parts.Skip(1), Function (r, p) New String() { r, p }).SelectMany(Function (x) x)))
End Function
```

For this:

```
Dim sample As String = "TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE STAR FISH"
Console.Write(ReplaceNthValue(sample, "TWINKLE", "MAD", 2))
```

I get this:

```
TWINKLE MAD LITTLE STAR FISH
```